# Asset images is not loading when the website is in offline mode in angular

Tags: angular

i have a retry screen if the user is in offline mode iam showing a image and json animation file on that screen

but the problem is when network is disconnected that image and json file also not loading from my assets folder iam getting below error on that occasion

:4200/assets/done.svg:1          GET http://localhost:4200/assets/done.svg net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED
zone.js:3454          GET http://localhost:4200/assets/retry.json net::ERR_INTERNET_DISCONNECTED

please help me to solve this issue?

Comment: Well, naturally you can't load resources when there is no connection. Perhaps you could load stuff like that in `app.component.ts` to the browsers cache

Comment: @0-9 so to cache these images what should i do ?can you suggest me an answer to fix this problem